# Default critical hit rate in Bravely Second

Tags: bravely-second

In Bravely Second, some weapons have listed a value for critical hit chance, for example, Katanas:

> Ise-no-Kami
>   Critical: 15

However, most weapons don't have a value for critical chance:

> Moon Glaive
>   Critical: ---

Yet, I often get critical hits while using weapons that "don't" have a critical hit chance. So there must be a base value for each character, but I cannot find it listed under any stats.
**So what is the default critical hit chance?**

Comment: nothing to back it up but i think it's 5% default to the character, and 15% from the weapon is additive, so you get 20% total